# jquery addClass is not working

Tags: jquery, html, addclass

I know there are other questions here asking the same sort of thing but I have looked at them all and I still can't find the problem in my uber simple code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="test">yo</div> 

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>

$('#test').addClass('4fuxsake');

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Is this for real? I can't see one thing wrong with this code yet it does nothing. Unbelievable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is correct. I assume that you open it in your browser from your local file system and did not upload it to a web server. Therefore jQuery cannot be loaded (`script src="//code...` means that the original protocol -- HTTP or HTTPS -- will be used, but both are not present if you open it locally)

Add the protocol:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

and it should work

Comment: I just tried a second browser and still in the source code I get no change... this is wak. I even cleared my cache on the first browser I used... so far Firefox and IE give me no change... now I'll try safari

Comment: I tried Chome 37 and Firefox 32, both worked. Did you right click > inspect element?

Comment: Make that Chrome because safari just freezes like the piece of %^&&* it is... anyway still no go, no class being added. This is queer, I think I need to reboot or something. Pascal I just did a right click and 'view source' same thing as inspect element really.

Comment: Nope, view source shows the original source, inspect element shows the current DOM

Comment: Pascal your are right, inspect element shows it but 'view source' does not... so there is a difference? The strange thing is at one stage it did work, I did a 'view source' and could see the class added.

Comment: Omg I am a noob... why did view source work for me at one stage though? It worked once, then didn't next time, then did again, then stopped working altogether... maybe I accidentally did 'inspect element' and didn't realize :/ anyway thanks for the heads up on that. It's a rookie mistake I won't be making ever again so I learned something here

Comment: Also when checking this fiddle that John S supplied http://jsfiddle.net/q88pn8yn/ ...if I go there using Firefox and highlight the word "yo" then right click that highlight and press "view selection source" it shows the changed class correctly. So how is "view selection source" different to "view source"?

Comment: "View selection source" always shows the current DOM, "View source" shows the original source code.

Comment: Yeah you are right that's exactly what happened. So today I learned there is a difference between "view source" and "view selection source"... omg I can't believe it. I've been messing with that for an hour abusing my computer monitor and declaring how crap jQuery is... and all along it was me and my noobness... anyway thanks Pascal

Answer (score 3):

Rule Number 1: Do NOT start a class name with a number! (W3:http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_selectors.asp)

Please try editing HTML side as removing **4** in the beginning of class name: http://jsfiddle.net/gyh3rqzs/1/

Use this:

```
.fuxsake
{
    color:red;
}
```

instead of:

```
.4fuxsake
{
    color:red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ertürk Öztürk for the 'rule of thumb' pointer, in this case though it wasn't the problem but I will keep your suggestion in mind in future.

Comment: First, that's really a good point. Just as a side note: This is only important if you use the classes in CSS, because CSS class selectors must not start with a number and will be ignored otherwise. However, in HTML is okay (= valid) to use class names that start with numbers.

Comment: I missed out the wrong script calling because i copied only the div to jsfiddle but it was not working there too with the jsfiddle's built-in jQuery. So I took a wrong turn. And don't swear to holy codes please.. Cheers! :)